# Angular Testing: Subscribing to service inside component constructor is giving undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

There is one service which is subscribed inside component's constructor. On writing test case it's giving undefined for this.data.

I have tried using spy's and mocks

```
  export class MyComponent {
  private data;
  constructor(private myservice:MyService) {
      this.myService.currentMessage.subscribe((message) => this.data = message);
   if(this.data) {
     let response = true;
  } else {
     let response = false;
}
```

Service.ts

```
  @Injectable()
  export class MyService {

    private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
    public currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
    constructor() { }
     changeMessage(message: string) {
     this.messageSource.next(message);
  }
 }
```

test case

```
    describe('MyComponent', () => {
    let component: MyComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
    let data:string = 'mystring';
    beforeEach(async(() => {
         const dataServiceStub = { currentMessage: { subscribe: () => ({}) } };
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      providers: [
    { provide: MyService, useValue: dataServiceStub }],
    }).compileComponents();
   }));
   beforeEach(() => {
         fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
         component = fixture.componentInstance;
         let service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MyService);
         service.currentMessage = Observable.of(data);
        //spyOn(service, 'currentMessage').and.returnValue(data);
   });
   it('can load instance', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   });
 });
```

Comment: Please provide more info on the error you're getting (if any). Also, if the issue is "On writing test case it's giving undefined", you should edit your answer to make the title reflect that, and also explain what is "giving undefined" and at which point in your code.

Comment: @GSCDC updated the question,  this.data = message here this.data is getting undefined

Comment: So you mean `message` is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's something I'm missing, the issue is because your constructor is finishing before you change the service's observable.

```
 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent); // The MyComponent constructor runs here
 component = fixture.componentInstance;
 let service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MyService);
 service.currentMessage = Observable.of(data); // The Observable is changed here.
```

To fix this, I *think* you need to change the `currentMessage` observable to read from `data` in the mock service you provide.

```
const dataServiceStub = { currentMessage: Observable.of(data) };
```

Comment: suggested change throwing an error 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Observable_1.Observable.of(data)'

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be `spy`ing **after** you are constructing your object. This means that your `observable` already fires before your `spy` is created.

Try `spy` on it before you construct the component.

```
let service;
  beforeEach(() => {
         spyOn(service, 'currentMessage').and.returnValue(whatever you want to return);

         fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
         component = fixture.componentInstance;

         service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MyService);
         service.currentMessage = Observable.of(data);
   });
```

Also your pattern in your `.ts` file looks a bit off.

`this.data` will always be undefined because your `if` statement happens immediately after the previous line, **not** after the observable returns. To fix this, you'll need to do the following.

```
  export class MyComponent {
  private data;
  constructor(private myservice:MyService) {
      this.myService.currentMessage.subscribe((message) => {
        this.data = message
        if(this.data) {
          let response = true;
        } else {
          let response = false;
        }
     });
```

This could be simplified by just checking `if (message)` and avoiding the field entirely.
Hope this helps!

Comment: service variable is undefined with suggested change